# MySQL : Return random value from each column

Tags: mysql

*Note: This might be a strange question.*

I have a table containing first name and last name, which schema as follow (table name: **random_names**):

```
id          INT             PRIMARY, AUTO INCREMENT
first_name  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL
last_name   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL
```

I would like to use a query to fetch a random value from `first_name` and `last_name`. Currently I use 2 queries to fetch the value:

```
SELECT first_name FROM random_names ORDER BY rand()
SELECT last_name FROM random_names ORDER BY rand()
```

But I wish I can output a list of random results in 1 result output. What did I miss ?

Comment: Do you want just one name or all the names in a random order?  If you want more than one row, do you want to allow duplicates (all rows independently selected) or do you really want a shuffle (first one is random, remaining are random as long as they're not the same as any prior row)?

Comment: just like shuffling the table records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    (select first_name from random_names order by rand() limit 1) as random_first_name, 
    (select last_name from random_names order by rand() limit 1) as random_last_name;
```

though for tables of any size it is much faster if you programmatically determine the number of entries and pick a random offset for each column:

```
select
    (select first_name from random_names order by rand() limit $first_name_offset,1) as random_first_name, 
    (select last_name from random_names order by rand() limit $last_name_offset,1) as random_last_name;
```

where the offsets are a random number from 0 to one less than the result of `select count(*) from random_names`.

Followup question:

> but how about list out result count equal to the number of values in original table? (just like shuffle the data in the table)

I'd do that like this:

```
create temporary table rand_last (id int(11) primary key auto_increment, last_name text) select last_name from random_names order by rand();
create temporary table rand_first (id int(11) primary key auto_increment, first_name text) select first_name from random_names order by rand();
select first_name, last_name from rand_first inner join rand_last using (id);
```

or possibly like this (assuming random_names has an 'id' primary key):

```
create temporary table rand_one (id int(11) primary key auto_increment, random_names_id int(11)) select id random_names_id from random_names order by rand();
create temporary table rand_two (id int(11) primary key auto_increment, random_names_id int(11)) select id random_names_id from random_names order by rand();
select rand_first.first_name, rand_last.last_name from rand_one inner join rand_two using (id) inner join random_names rand_first on rand_one.random_names_id=rand_first.id inner join random_names rand_last on rand_two.random_names_id=rand_last.id;
```

Comment: but how about list out result count equal to the number of values in original table? (just like shuffle the data in the table)

Comment: can't believe a simple task needs to do so many steps. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can get all possible pairs of `first_name` and `last_name` in random order by following query:

```
select *
from (select first_name from random_names) a,
     (select last_name from random_names) b
order by rand();
```

Comment: unsurprisingly, that goes *really slowly* on a table with even just a thousand entries.

Comment: @ysth Sure it is. Using cartesian product of a thousand entries would generate a million rows. And ordering them by `rand()`... Yes, it it slow. But if the data set is small enough, it's simple way to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this-

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM random_names ORDER BY rand()
```

OR

```
SELECT concat(first_name," ",last_name) fullname FROM random_names ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: gets only first_name and last_name from the same row, not what the question asks for